# BWF Files -- Why didn't someone tell me about them sooner?

Tags: bwf, vegas, reaper

I'm sure you've noticed, but I've been doing a bit of video editing at my work -- video in Vegas Movie Studio, then audio in Reaper -- and last week I imported my WAVs from Vegas into Reaper and saw those beautiful red marker lines.

I immediately knew what they were -- I'd been using makers like crazy in Vegas -- and they've made everything SOO much easier.  It's really nice to be able to edit dialogue without having the video open (it saves me a bit of RAM), and to just know where I'm at.

In any case, I didn't want to ask a question so much as elate how much I now love BWFs.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't Pro-Tools use BWF natively?

Wait, it's not supposed to sound like that...

I just want to know if I can get in on the BWF party.

Answer (score 1):

What does the Badminton World Federation have anything to do with sound design?? ok lame joke... But yeah, super convenient. I'm also really liking Reaper as an alternative DAW to Logic Pro. I just recently started learning about BWF files myself, haven't come across a specific instance where I needed to use them, but at any rate, I figure it's good to know about them.

Comment: I started using Reaper at work, where I didn't have Sonar, and I only find myself missing a few things -- like all my plugins and auto-routed busses.

Answer (score 1):

BWF WAVS do rock.  Yes, they work in Pro Tools as well. I enjoy dropping markers in files on my 702t when recording sound effects and keeping a written log for faster editing later.

Be careful using .wav files in Final Cut Pro though.  May sound dumb, but I and others have experienced serious freezes and other issues related to .wav files in Final Cut Pro.  I always convert all of my files to .aif before importing them into Final Cut.

Comment: My h4n places markers, as well. :)

Comment: Interesting to hear that about Final Cut. I've been having crash issues with FCP and .wav files as well.

Comment: I love placing markers while recording.  Then I don't have to stop recording and risk missing something good, and I don't have to waste time looking through everything.